# About: 開いた口がふさがらない

Tags: words

`開いた口がふさがらない` means: `Feel shocked`, or `Unbelievable`, right?

**My question is:**

What does `ふさがらない` mean, what is that verb without `ない`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[塞【ふさ】がる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/192230/m0u/) is an intransitive verb which means *to shut*, *to close*, etc.

Comment: Can u teach how to type `ふさ` above `塞`, that's useful.

Comment: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/807/5010